# Java AffineTransformOp memory question

Tags: java, image-processing

I'm trying to apply an AffineTransform to an image in Java. Here's the code that I'm running.

```
AffineTransformOp op =
        new AffineTransformOp(atx, interactive ? interpolationInteractive : interpolationNormal);
displayImage = op.filter(displayImage, null);
```

Where atx is a valid AffineTransform object.  This code seems to run fine, but it leaves a very large amount of memory around after I do it a number of times, and eventually my program runs out of memory.

I'm sure this line is the culprit, because if I comment out applying the transformation, then no memory leak occurs.

I have 3 questions:

1. Why is the syntax for the filter method so strange (it takes in a src, and destination, and returns a destination)?
2. Why does this cause a memory leak?
3. How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BufferedImage`, depending on the resolution of the source, may be quite large and expensive to create. With that in mind:

1. `.filter()` method syntax takes destination parameter to avoid unnecessary creation of `BufferedImage` copy if you already have one ready. In other words, if I need to process a sequence of (compatible) images, reusing one buffered image as destination for all transformations would be a better approach then creating a new one each time.
2. Transformation itself does not cause a memory leak. You directly or indirectly holding onto all the `BufferedImage` instances you've created does.
3. That depends on what you're doing. For starters, you need to find out where your `BufferedImage` instances are being referenced. Calling `flush()` won't hurt either.

Comment: I just revisited this issue, and attempted to use the other form of the filter() method.  However, I've noticed that when I use this form it is much slower than the image = op.filter(image, null).  Any ideas why?

Comment: The "other" form being the one where you pass in `BufferedImage` destination? It should not be slower; certainly not much slower. Are you timing the actual `filter()` operation or some surrounding code as well? Or do you mean `Raster`-based by "other"? I don't think that should be much slower either but I've never used it.